# Smart Lock does not work anymore

Tags: nexus-7

Suddenly Smart Lock on my Nexus 7 (flo) unrooted/5.0.2 and on my Samsung GT i9300 rooted/pa 5.0.2 alpha does not work anymore.

My solution: I uninstalled the Google-Play-Service Updates.